# No EntityManager bound to this thread JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a POJO(Myclass in this example) which I persist/update/delete in my app.

I detect changes to that object using a listener class and then in listener class I save the changes to another table.

```
Here is my class (dummy example) :

EntityListeners({MyListener.class})
class MyClass {
  String name;
  String surname;

  /*...getters...setter..etc */

  public void save() {
    JPA.em().persist(this);
    return this;
  }

  public void update() {
    JPA.em().merge(this);
  }
}

class MyListener {
   @preUpdate
   public void preUpdate() {
    /*...some logic to save the changes irrelevant*/
    someAuditObj.createWithData(.......);
    someAuditObj.save();
   }
}
```

I'm building my web app using `play framework v2.1.3`, and all this was working great, I was really happy the way it works.

Today I updated play framework to a newer version `v2.2.1`. 
And the for some reason when instance of `MyClass` changes and the listener picks up the change and it tries to save the changes the transaction fails and I find this in the log :

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread
```

So it took me a while to figure out that for some reason transaction is not propagated to listener and then I tried something to fix it (Listener class):

```
@preUpdate
       public void preUpdate() {
        /*...some logic to save the changes irrelevant*/
       JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {
             @Override
             public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                      someAuditObj.createWithData(.......);
                      someAuditObj.save();
       });
       }
```

So this fixes it, and it works like before without issues.

My question(s) is :

1. Why did it work before without meddling manually with transactions with earlier version of play framework
2. Is there a better way of achieving the same thing more elegantly (I'm not sure that is the right word for it)?

**Update**

This is my controller method :

```
@Transactional
    public Result updateName(Long id, String name){
        MyClass c = MyClass.findById(id);
        c.setName(name);
        c.update();

        return ok();
    }
```

So transaction should be propagated to all methods right? but why not to listener as well?

My estimate was this :

if a method has @Transactional annotation then all calls that happens inside should be in a transaction?

Comment: Could you post your controller code which invokes your update method?  Async actions don't necessarily run on the same thread. That would explain the error message you are seeing. I believe the way you have it set up now is the best way to do achieve transactional guarantee.

Comment: I am guessing the problem is that `preUpdate` is running in a different thread, which sounds like a bug. Do you get a similar error using a different callback (e.g. prePersist)? I realize prePersist is not appropriate for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you got same problem as mine. Look at my issue: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2042
Same JPA code works with 2.1.0 but not working with 2.2.1
So i think it's a bug.

> 1. Why did it work before without meddling manually with transactions
>      with earlier version of play framework
> 2. Is there a better way of
>      achieving the same thing more elegantly (I'm not sure that is the
>      right word for it)?

We have just to wait till this issue will solved or wait some explanation about using threads with JPA transaction from play2 developers in this issue. At this moment issue is open.

Answer (score 1):

In our view, the problem is that JPA.withTransaction() (and @Transactional uses this too) blocks cannot be nested since .withTransaction() unbinds the em unconditionally, and if its an inner .withTransaction(), the outer block will be left without a bound em.

So this test fails at c.save() (save persists the entity in our case)

```
@Test
public void nestedJPACalls() {

    JPATestEntity a = new JPATestEntity();
    JPATestEntity b = new JPATestEntity();
    JPATestEntity c = new JPATestEntity();

    JPA.withTransaction(() -> {

        a.save();

        JPA.withTransaction(() -> {

            b.save();

        });

        c.save();
    });
}
```

The .withTransaction() methods should check if the em is already bound, and if so, neither bind nor unbind it. I've added that to the discussion at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2042

We're working on a clean solution now. A temporary but ugly solution is to just try/catch and run your code inside JPA.withTransaction() only if you get the "No EntityManager bound to this thread" exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create receipt asynch
            Akka.future(new Callable() {
                public Object call() {
                    // Issue Receipt
                    JPA.withTransaction(new F.Callback0() {

                        @Override
                        public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            issueReceipt(pgTxn); // test
                        }
                    });
                    return null;
                }
            });
```